# django-tinymce: Using different options for different instances

Tags: python, django, tinymce, django-tinymce

I have a model with an `HTMLField` which can be edited with a TinyMCE control in the admin. However, I would like to be able to give different options to TinyMCE depending on which instance of the model is being edited. How can I do this?

(For example, if the user is editing the `SimplePage` instance whose slug is `technologies`, I want TinyMCE to use the default CSS file, but if its editing the `SimplePage` whose slug is `ticker`, I want to use a different CSS file.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a `Media` class in your ModelAdmin with additional JavaScript and CSS for the admin ([like here](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AddWYSIWYGEditor)). Your JavaScript doesn't know the slug of the current object, let's change that.

First create one of the following directory structures in your templates directory: "admin/`your-app`" for an app or "admin/`your-app`/`your-model`" for a specific model only ([see the Django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates)).

Then create a file "change_form.html" in that directory and put something similar to this in there:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block extrahead %}
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var MYAPP_objectSlug = "{{ original.slug|escapejs }}";
</script>
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

This will extend the usual "change_form.html" of the admin and extend the `extrahead` block to set a JavaScript variable with your object slug (`original` is your object).

Now adapt the JavaScript file that does the `tinyMCE.init` to use a different CSS file based 
 on the JavaScript variable `MYAPP_objectSlug`.

```
if (MYAPP_objectSlug == "ticker"){
    var MYAPP_cssFile = "../css/special.css"; // change to your path
} else {
    var MYAPP_cssFile = "../css/default.css"; // change to your path
}

tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    content_css : MYAPP_cssFile,
    ...
});
```